# pkgcloud and GCE (Google Compute Engine)

Tags: node.js, openstack, google-compute-engine, pkgcloud

Is it possible to control GCE (Google Compute Engine) using pkgcloud for Node.js?

This page says "The GCE APIs are implemented as first-class citizens of OpenStack Compute":
http://www.cloudscaling.com/blog/cloud-computing/why-google-compute-engine-for-openstack/

...and pkgcloud supports OpenStack.  But I haven't seen anywhere where support is explicitly affirmed for GCE and if OAuth is handled by pkgcloud (speaking somewhat uninformedly here) and haven't seen any sample code specifically for GCE.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the Google APIs Node.js Client available at [1]? It has built-in support for OAuth 2.0.

[1] - https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client

Comment: yes, but I was hoping to talk to all cloud providers through a single interface.  I think it's possible with pkgcloud and OpenStack.  I just need to spend some time trying it out.  Thanks for your comment.